# Snowflake Connector not working After Kafka Advertised ports altered ( AWS MSK )

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk

I have a AWS MSK cluster, I am following the [AWS MSK Goldman Sachs Single NLB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-goldman-sachs-builds-cross-account-connectivity-to-their-amazon-msk-clusters-with-aws-privatelink/)

The Cluster is using IAM Auth.
The Snowflake connector works fine till the advertised ports are set to there default 9098, but when i alter the ports to lets say 9001/9002 as i have 2 brokers, the connector fails to connect to the brokers and crashes.

I would also like to add one more point here, if i try to connect from a EC2 within the same VPC, the cluster is still functional, no issues, observed there.

Command used to Alter ports:

```
./kafka-configs \
--bootstrap-server $B1:9098 \
--entity-type brokers \
--entity-name 1 \
--alter \
--command-config client_iam.properties \
--add-config advertised.listeners=[CLIENT_IAM://$B1:9001,REPLICATION://b-1-internal.$KF_DOMAIN:9093,REPLICATION_SECURE://b-1-internal.$KF_DOMAIN:9095]
```

Error in Connector Logs:

```
[Worker-03e3eee9d7f02cfe6] [2022-09-28 16:52:43,013] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-8] Connection to node 2 (b-2.XXX.XXX.c16.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/INTERNAL_IP) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:782)
[Worker-03e3eee9d7f02cfe6] [2022-09-28 16:52:44,620] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=__amazon_msk_connect_cluster_XXX-json_631e64b8-7451-4c20-aabf-6a5fb80081a6-4] Reading to end of config log; current config state offset: 12 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1198)
[Worker-03e3eee9d7f02cfe6] [2022-09-28 16:52:47,620] WARN [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=__amazon_msk_connect_cluster_XXX-json_631e64b8-7451-4c20-aabf-6a5fb80081a6-4] Didn't reach end of config log quickly enough (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1209)
[Worker-03e3eee9d7f02cfe6] java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for future


[Worker-0c13b739d8fb9e210]  rest.advertised.host.name = INTERNAL_IP
[Worker-0c13b739d8fb9e210]  rest.advertised.listener = HTTP
[Worker-0c13b739d8fb9e210]  rest.advertised.port = null
```

Snowflake Connector config

```
connector.class=com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector
snowflake.topic2table.map=boosterflow:boosterflow
tasks.max=8
topics=boosterflow
snowflake.topic.sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
buffer.flush.time=60
snowflake.url.name=XXXX.snowflakecomputing.com:443
snowflake.database.name=XXXXX
snowflake.schema.name=XXXXXX
buffer.count.records=10000
snowflake.user.name=XXXXX
snowflake.private.key="XXXXXXX"
snowflake.topic.sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
snowflake.topic.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
value.converter=com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeJsonConverter
snowflake.topic.sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
buffer.size.bytes=5000000
```

Comment: Are you sure it's Snowflake Kafka connector not working? What about enabling logs on Snowflake Kafka based on this [link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-ts.html#reporting-issues)?

Comment: The connector stops consuming or alteast fails to connect after the advertised ports changed, but my clients in a different vpc from outside is still able to push and consume data, and even the clients in the same vpc just works, i am not exactly sure, why would the connector have a issue, if other clients are working, the above are logs from cloudwatch for this connector, and FYI, the connector some how still shows running, its just that reading data has stopped completely, and i get the above in the logs

Comment: Well, did you modify the Connect AdminClient to use the new authentication scheme? Look at the bootstrap servers, not the advertised listeners

Comment: @OneCricketeer i have updated my question with the connector config which i am using, honestly i am  just completely lost, i would really appreciate if u can pin point something within this config, or something that i need to add,  FYI, this config works, before advertised port aleration.

Comment: And no i did not modified anything after advertised port change

Comment: You changed how clients need to connect to your broker. You may need `admin.client.override` settings in the Connector config or `connect.admin` properties in the worker config (please add that file as well) to use those new sasl IAM configs. You also need to change `bootstrap.servers`, of course

Comment: did u solve @Ali ?

Comment: nope, it was not enough info for me to move ahead, i changed my architecture, got frustrated and moved on